# DRF Serializer foreign key reverse lookup

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I'm trying to send the following HTTP Post API request to create a new `EventInterest` object. How can I accomplish this in a smallest payload instead of sending the entire object? I'm attempting an extra layer of security-through-obfuscation and instead of using the default integer `pk`, how can I use `uuid` for `Event` and `username` for `User`? .... Or do the extra SQL lookups negate the benefits of simplifying the payload and I should just use `pk`?

models.py

```
class Event(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    description = models.TextField(max_length=500)
    uuid = models.UUIDField(default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False, unique=True, db_index=True, blank=True)

class EventInterest(models.Model):
    event = models.ForeignKey(Event)
    sender = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL)  # from User
```

api.py

```
class EventInterestViewSet(mixins.CreateModelMixin, GenericViewSet):

    queryset = models.EventInterest.objects.all()
    serializer_class = serializers.EventInterestSerializer
    lookup_field = 'uuid'
```

serializer.py

```
class EventInterestSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    # event = serializers.SlugRelatedField(read_only=True, slug_field='uuid')
    # recipient = serializers.SlugRelatedField(read_only=True, slug_field='username')
    # sender = serializers.SlugRelatedField(read_only=True, slug_field='username')

    class Meta:
        model = models.EventInterest
        fields = (
            'event',  #works with pk, want uuid
            'sender',  # works with pk, want username
        )
```

HTTP Post:

```
{
    "event": "da9290c6-f6f8-4d27-bfe0-d388ed911fe8",
    "sender":"eX8gkxJNDREv"  //this is the username field
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you defined `uuid` in `Event` model, you have to define `uuid` in `User` model too. In order to do that, you have to extend the default user model. Then you have to override the `create()` method of `EventInterestSerializer` to do a lookup on respective UUID field instead of `pk`
**`models.py`**

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser


class User(AbstractUser):
    uuid = models.UUIDField(default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False, unique=True, db_index=True)


class Event(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    description = models.TextField(max_length=500)
    uuid = models.UUIDField(default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False, unique=True, db_index=True)


class EventInterest(models.Model):
    event = models.ForeignKey(Event)
    sender = models.ForeignKey(User)
```

**`serializer.py`**

```
class EventInterestSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = EventInterest
        fields = ('event', 'sender',)

    def create(self, validated_data):
        try:
            return EventInterest.objects.get(event__uuid=validated_data['event'],
                                             sender__uuid=validated_data['sender'])
        except EventInterest.DoesNotExist:
            raise serializers.ValidationError("No matching data found")
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to make your UUIDField as primary key. Just like this:

```
class Event(models.Model):
    uuid = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4)
    ....
```

Comment: And also the username in the user model